# MATLAB view a YUV422 Image

Tags: image, matlab

The question is how to view a yuv422 data using matlab?

Additional information:
A microcontroller connected to a Image sensor that provides data as YUV422, I was able to view the image using a specific java program.

The data is viewed as the following example “128 74 83 93...”

Knowing that it is only a single frame.

EDIT:
The following link contains the data that was obtained from the image sensor (OV7670 as YUV422, 320,240)
[Data](https://1drv.ms/t/s!ApvN8RdEE8zi3kyvwJlpzEGeWLT8)

Comment: Maybe you could identify the sensor, and share the image and its dimensions?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes I will edit the post and try to add a text file of the data I got from the Image sensor: Image sensor is OV7670, the Dimensions are : 320x240

Comment: A text file? Huh? It should be binary.

Comment: The file your provided has 76,800 numbers in it, each corresponding to one byte. If your image is 320x240 pixels, that makes 76,800 pixels. So your file cannot be YUV422 because that requires 16 bits per pixel whereas you only have 8 bits per pixel. So your image would appear to be greyscale (1 byte per pixel), surely?

Comment: @Mark Setchell it actually has 76,801 numbers, which is even more puzzling.

Comment: Is the image supposed to look like this? http://thesetchells.com/z.jpg

Comment: @MarkSetchell No it is not supposed to look like this. I need to learn how to write as binary most probably, and thank you guys for the help

Comment: Ping me (using the @-sign) again when you have some binary data and I'll give you a hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using serial port to read image data, then store it in an array and reshape it to the size 320x240 using

```
reshape(arr,[240,320])
```

then you can convert YUV (YCbCr in matlab) to rgb using

```
rgbmap = ycbcr2rgb(ycbcrmap)
```

finally, show image using

```
imshow(rgbmap,[])
```